# perform a search using pdo code

Tags: php, pdo

i have a pdo code to perform a search through a database table using keyword 'fname', however i am getting an error

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];    

        $sth = "SELECT * FROM features_for_office WHERE fname LIKE :fname ";

        $stmt = $dsn->prepare($sth);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', '%' . $fname . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $locations = $sth->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode( $locations );

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

would appreciate if someone could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$db` for connection and using `$dsn` instead of `$db`

same thing you are doing with fetch all. You are using `$stmt` for execute but using `$sth` for fetch result

```
$stmt = $dsn->prepare($sth);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', '%' . $fname . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$locations = $sth->fetchAll();
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sth);
$stmt->bindValue(':fname', '%' . $fname . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$locations = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: i have named the connection dsn, therefore used it in place of db

Comment: but here you are connecting to dsn using `$db`, try to change it once and check the output

Comment: now i am getting error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Comment: now change `$locations = $sth->fetchAll();` to `$locations = $stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: getting error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: got the error nw, have used name instead of fname, thanks for ur help